# Xcode UI Testing UICollectionViewCell + UITableViewCell Focus

Tags: xcode, swift, tvos, xcode-ui-testing

I'm attempting to test the focus of a UICollectionView and a UITableView in a tvOS app. When I call the following code with a UICollectionView on screen: `XCUIApplication().cells.debugDescription` I get at least one cell that is currently focused. However, calling the same code on UITableViewCell, no cells return a trait with focused.

Is this behaviour others have been experiencing, are there any workarounds?